# Unity Animator not entering entry state

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation, game-development

I am trying to make a very simple animation in unity where an element fades in and out based on if a character enters a box collider of an NPC. When running the game, I have my Animator window open, and the blue horizontal line that normally appears under the entry state isn't even showing up. When looking at the previews of my animations the sprite I'm animating fades in and out so I know that isn't the problem. For some reason my entry state isn't even being reached and I can't figure out why.

I have the animation clips set up for an open and close state, I have a script that takes a public Animator and dragged the gameobject with the animator into the respective slot in the editor.

Here's the file that triggers the animation: (PS: I've inserted Debug.Log statements and know for a fact I am entering the if(playerInRange) condition.

```
public class DialogueTrigger : MonoBehaviour {

[SerializeField] private GameObject visualCue;

[SerializeField] private TextAsset inkJSON;

public Animator animator;

bool playerInRange;

void Awake() {
    playerInRange = false;
    visualCue.SetActive(false);
}

void Update() {
    if (playerInRange) {
        animator.SetBool("IsOpen", true);
        if (InputManager.GetInstance().GetInteractPressed()) {
            Debug.Log(inkJSON.text);
        }
    }
    else {
        animator.SetBool("IsOpen", false);
    }
}

void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other) {
    if (other.gameObject.tag == "Player") {
        playerInRange = true;
    }
}

void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D other) {
    if (other.gameObject.tag == "Player") {
        playerInRange = false;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: aaaaand of course the second I post on stack overflow I figure it out. I needed to remove the visualCue.SetActive("False") line as that was disabling the sprite I was trying to animate, had that in there from a tutorial I was following earlier.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).